# Restore Database backup from code?

Tags: c#, .net, backup, database-restore

I have an application extension which I need to test.  Part of the extension applies some updates to the application database schema (via the applications API).  i want to test that given version 1 of the application when my class is run the schema becomes v1.1 and that certain queries for items which should exist in 1.1 return correctly.  I have  backup of the database at schema v1.0 and what I would like to do in my tests is:

1/ restore the database from a backup

2/ call the code which does the update

3/ call several methods which verify that the schema updates have succeeded

4/restore the database from a backup

Are there classes I can use to do this restore in my c# code, or do I have to execute the command in shell process?

Comment: Are you running SQL Server or are you aiming to do this via something else like ODBC or MySQL?

Comment: I am running sql server, but an option that would allow this to work with oracle as well would be very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are uysing SQL Server, you could use the SQL Management objects (SMO)

An example can be found [here](http://blog.falafel.com/2007/07/08/GetMetaDataDoBackupsWithSQLManagementObjectsSMO.aspx)

Kindness,

Dan